# How to dynamic generate pages in php?

Tags: php, html, web

I'm doing a web app with PHP in which users have different number of tabs in the menu depending on a certain number of things, one user can have one tab in the menu where another user has ten.

I've managed to dynamically generate the menu items but now I don't know how to create files (pages) where the user gets redirected once he presses on any of the menu tabs.

All these files look the same the only thing that changes are the text, just some strings.

Summing up, what I want to do is:

- Generate and destroy files automatically when the user has to consult something
- How to link the menu tabs (href) to them automatically

Comment: I thinks you need database. When user click on tab just pass it's id to next page and then check in database with that id. and retrive that data to that page from database.

Comment: To know more what kind of page you want generated it would be good to know what kind of data you are using and want generated. Is it data from a database or from an API or calculated etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best would be to use a PHP page as template you could call it.

Lets say for example a user is logged in and clicks the view data page **(data.php)**
on your link you could have something like this:

```
<a href="data.php?id=<?php echo $USER_ID;?>"></a>
```

and in **data.php**:

```
<?php
$USER_ID = htmlspecialchars($_GET["id"])
//SQL Request to get user priviledge and authentificate
//OR
//Check the cookie session for information
if (user_priviledge == 0)
{
//
//Show only data for 0 users
//
}elseif (user_priviledge == 1) {
//
//Show only data for 1 users
//
}
?>
```

This may not be the solution you wanted but your question wasn't very clear either so if you need any other information make sure to bring more precision.

Answer (score 0):

The condition which are using for tab use same condition to show page.
 But add that condition in your text.
Because your text is changing not page I think.

I this this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

since all files will look the same and only variables will change, you can create one php file and just send the necessary data when a user clicks on the tab to assign to the variables in that page. You do not need to keep on creating custom pages for each and every tab.

Provide some code which you have written for this so that we can help you further